# Knockout, get JSON from View Model after mapping it

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I start with empty view model, then I do an ajax request for data from database. Collected data I mapping using Knockout.Mapping plugin to view model. 
Like this:

```
var myName = new function(){
this.viewModel = {};
var getData = function () {    
    var mapping = {
        'Members': {
        create: function (options) {
            return new UserMode(options.data);
        }
        }
    }
    $.ajax({
        url: 'api/board',
        data: $.param({"BoardId": 1}),
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
            this.viewModel = ko.mapping.fromJS(data, mapping);
            ko.applyBindings(this.viewModel);
        },
    });
}
};
```

Then I  opened a JavaScript console in Chrome and typed:

```
ko.toJSON(myName.viewModel);
```

And results is

```
"{}"
```

I expected to see viewModel with data from server, not empty object.

Comment: Have you actually called the getData function?

Comment: Yes I did called getData function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You made a little confusion, I think you should call applybindings before doing your AJAX loading stuff.

I updated one of my old fiddle to replicate your problem, check it out, hope it will help you!

http://jsfiddle.net/ingro/Buscp/

Comment: It should work either way, but I also prefer to establish the bindings first and then request the data.